# What else should I check to troubleshoot an outdoor post light?

Tags: wiring

Bulb quit working in outdoor light post, changed bulb. Still did not work.  Changed the light post eye control, nothing. Re checked all wiring.  Circuit breaker also controls porch lights, works.  What else should be checked?

Comment: When you say "re-checked all wiring", what does that mean? Do you have voltage at the fixture?

Comment: Check and see if the center conductor on the fixture flattened out some times these sag and don’t make contact causing a no light condition. Is there a GFCI in the entry or outside that the light gets power from on the same circuit?

Comment: re-checked wiring entailed correct connections and having power.  Bought house in 1973 no known GFCI outside, only in bathrooms I installed. I will check the center conductor on fixture.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Check on the walls of your garage, inside and out for a GFCI outlet. Also check at the base of the light post. GFCI's are usually used for light posts and are usually to blame for what you're experiencing.

Comment: I would agree but op said the bkr controls the porch light that works.

Comment: @EdBeal The GFCI could be downstream from the porch lights and breaker  or even at the base of the light post